# select time from intervale of time in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, time, strftime

I have a question about the intervale of times in Mysql.

I have a Mysql database where i have a timetable with subjects and teachers that give the subjects.

With:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
$weekday=strftime("%A");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$time=date("H:i:s", time());
```

I get the time and weekday.

But my question is:

If the time i get is for example 11:25:00 h, i want to get the class which is between 11:00:00 and 12:00:00 where i guess that all the classes take 1 hour.

If the time is: 09:55:00 h, it would be between 09:00:00 and 10:00:00.

I wrote for the weekday:

```
$date_query = "select distinct course, class, subject from timetable where date='".$weekday."'and id_user='".$id_user."'";

$result = mysql_query($date_query);
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = date("H", time()) . ":00:00";
```

Assuming all classes run on the hour, that'll get you the time value of the current class. With more information about the timetable table we might find I've missed the point though. :)